# azure web app for containers uWSGI listen queue of socket full

Tags: django, azure, linux-kernel, uwsgi, azure-web-app-for-containers

My app running in a docker container on Azure Webapps for Containers (linux).
I found out my server is getting error when listening queue increases.

log:

```
uWSGI listen queue of socket "127.0.0.1:37400" (fd: 3) full !!! **(101/100)**
```

I have added '''--listen 4096''' option to increase the queue. but my server still throws error.
log:

```
uWSGI listen queue of socket "127.0.0.1:37400" (fd: 3) full !!! **(129/128)**
```

some reference says need to increase `net.core.somaxconn` but I couldn't increase it.
log:

```
sysctl: error: 'net.core.somaxconn' is an unknown key
```

Any idea what i am missing?
Thanks

**EDIT**

Let me share my Dockerfile

```
FROM python:3.6-alpine

RUN apk update && \
    apk add python3 python3-dev \
            gcc musl-dev linux-headers zlib zlib-dev libffi libffi-dev\
            freetype freetype-dev jpeg jpeg-dev \
            postgresql-dev

WORKDIR /code
COPY . /code/

ENV LANG c.UTF-8
ENV DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE myproject.settings.prod
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt

EXPOSE 80

CMD ["uwsgi", "--plugins", "http,python", \
              "--http", "0.0.0.0:80", \
              "--wsgi-file", "/code/myproject/wsgi.py", \
              "--master", \
              "--listen", "4096", \
              "--die-on-term", \
              "--single-interpreter", \
              "--harakiri", "30", \
              "--reload-on-rss", "512", \
              "--post-buffering-bufsize", "8192"]
```

Comment: Which image do you use and what do you change in the image as you need?

Comment: @CharlesXu I added my Dockerfile, please check. Thank you

Comment: It seems there is no problem with your Dockerfile. You need to check your application.

Comment: @CharlesXu yeah, I think I have to do something in azure, but I have no idea how to configure it.

Comment: If it happens in your application, then I have no idea. Maybe you can take a look at this [issue](https://github.com/unbit/uwsgi/issues/1685).

Comment: @CharlesXu What I tried to ask was how to set somaxconn in azure web app container. Not just in my app. Thank you for your help.

Comment: You can try to use the [environment variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-common?toc=%2fazure%2fapp-service%2fcontainers%2ftoc.json) in the azure web app.